# iTunes Sync "MyAppName"Failed to install- IPA File

Tags: ios

Recently, I have submitted my app and been accepted. However functionalities that I have built are not same with app version. Then I have contacted app developer and they told me as follows:

```
"To test that build, "Distribute…" it as an IPA, from the Organizer window in
Xcode. Then install the IPA by dragging it onto the iTunes icon on the dock
and syncing with your device."
```

Now, I created my IPA and drag and drop this file on Itunes and then to my iphone and it shows failing to sync error! I dont know what I am doing wrong? any guidance?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Try to install the IPA from Organizer instead of iTunes. To do it open Organizer from: `Xcode > Window > Organizer`, then select `Applications` under your device and click the `+` button to add the IPA.

Comment: This method shows a more useful error message than iTunes. For me it was an expired signing certificate.

Comment: If I can add more than +1 I would, many thanks Hesham Abd-Elmegid.

Comment: @Hesham, What if a client or a person doesn't have Xcode installed and wants to install it from itunes only. Please advice as I'm facing the same issue.

Comment: I personally never send IPAs for people to test. It's just much easier to use something like TestFlight to distribute your betas.

Comment: I can't find my devices on Organizer, can you show me a screenshot to find that section?