# "The iPhone could not be synced because this computer is no longer authorized for purchased items that are on this iPhone:

Tags: ios, authorization, itunes, ipa

I have an app in development and need to load the latest IPA for testing, a process performed through iTunes, like syncing anything else. When I try and sync I get the message, "The iPhone could not be synced because this computer is no longer authorized for purchased items that are on this iPhone."

I did the research on the internet and haven't found an adequate answer. I've tried:

— Being sure I'm logged into the same iTunes account as the iPhone.

— Deauthorizing then Authorizing the computer, after which I get an alert saying the computer has been successfully authorized, resulting in the same error message again when I again try and sync.

— Removing the SC Info folder, as found in this article: http://support.apple.com/kb/TS1389 . I guess I have the only Mac that has no trace af any such "SC Info" folder anywhere in the system (OS 10.6.8).

— Logged in under every conceivable account configuration (computer admin, device account, etc...) to no avail.

I have to get this IPA imported into the iPhone. It's the same process as syncing anything else. If anyone has a solution, please send it along. Clock is loudly ticking.

Maybe a better question would be, Is there a way to import an IPA without using iTunes?

Many thanks.

Cayce

[image: Warning description]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You have apps on the phone that were purchased with a different Apple ID than the one that the computer is Authorized for. You need to add the Apple ID to iTunes that those apps were purchased with. It is OK to have iTunes authorized to more than one Apple ID.

Comment: How can you figure out either: which application was purchased with a different account or what was the ID of the different account ?

Comment: You couldn't figure out which application should be removed, because it is apple. You should remove all applications or bruteforce its combinations. Development process is not compatible with apple.

Answer (score 8):

I had this issue. Solution is to deleted the app that has been downloaded from different account (account other than used for building application).

Answer (score 4):

I almost had the same query and wanted to test the iPA asap.
So perhaps this would be the answer to you second question which is installing the iPA without the iTunes :

Try to install the IPA from Organizer instead of iTunes. To do it open Organizer from: Xcode > Window > Organizer, then select Applications under your device and click the + button to add the IPA.

[Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13816896/2810444)

Answer (score 1):

This phone contains apps that were purchased with different Apple ID than the one that the computer is authorized for. So you need to delete those apps to authorize this computer.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly make sure your iPhone is added to the developer portal and is included in the provisioning profile for the build of the app that you are hoping to test.

If you are wanting to avoid using iTunes then you could try using Testflight as you can distribute Ad-Hoc builds for testing without the need to use iTunes. It also means you can get other to test without needing to send them to IPA or physically get hold of the device.

[Testflight](https://www.testflightapp.com)

Answer (score 0):

**I have fixed this problem** by resetting all settings on the iPhone device (back to factory settings).

```
iPhone -> Settings -> General -> Reset -> Erase All Content and Settings
```

**Note:** this will delete all data and apps from the phone so consider  if this option is right for you before proceeding.

Once phone was reset, I connected it to the macBook and completed sync without any issues or additional steps taken.